# Unable to write function for df.columns to factorize()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
age           45211 non-null int64
job           45211 non-null object
marital       45211 non-null object
default       45211 non-null object
balance       45211 non-null int64
housing       45211 non-null object
loan          45211 non-null object
contact       45211 non-null object
day           45211 non-null int64
month         45211 non-null object
duration      45211 non-null int64
campaign      45211 non-null int64
pdays         45211 non-null int64
previous      45211 non-null int64
poutcome      45211 non-null object
conversion    45211 non-null int64
```

I want to do two things:

(1) I want to create two sub-dataframes which will be automatically separated by dtype=object and dtype=int64. I thought of something like this:

```
object_df=[]
int_df=[]

for i in df.columns:
   if dtype=object:
       *add column to object_df*
   else:
       *add column to int_df*
```

(2) Next, I want to use the columns from `object_df['job','marital','default','housing','loan','contact','month','poutcome']` and write a function which factorizes each column, so that categories will be converted to numbers. I thought of something like this:

```
job_values,job_labels= df['job'].factorize()
df['job_fac']=job_values
```

Since I would have to copy and paste those for all columns in the object_df, is there a way to write a neat dynamic function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) first:

```
object_df = df.select_dtypes(object)
int_df = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
```

And then create lambda function for `factorize`, [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
cols = ['job','marital','default','housing','loan','contact','month','poutcome']
df = df.join(object_df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).add_suffix('_fac'))
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
c = ['age', 'job', 'marital', 'default', 'balance', 'housing', 'loan', 'contact', 'day', 'month', 'duration', 'campaign', 'pdays', 'previous', 'poutcome', 'conversion']
cols = ['job','marital','default','housing','loan','contact','month','poutcome']
cols1 = np.setdiff1d(c, cols)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('abcde'), size=(3, len(cols))), columns=cols)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3, len(cols1))), columns=cols1)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reindex(columns=c)
print (df)
   age job marital default  balance housing loan contact  day month  duration  \
0    9   a       a       d        5       d    d       d    6     a         5   
1    4   a       a       c        2       b    d       d    7     c         1   
2    3   a       e       e        2       a    e       b    1     b         2   

   campaign  pdays  previous poutcome  conversion  
0         6      4         6        a           6  
1         3      4         9        d           4  
2         0      7         1        c           9
```

---

```
object_df = df.select_dtypes(object)
print (object_df)

  job marital default housing loan contact month poutcome
0   a       a       d       d    d       d     a        a
1   a       a       c       b    d       d     c        d
2   a       e       e       a    e       b     b        c

int_df = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
print (int_df)
   age  balance  day  duration  campaign  pdays  previous  conversion
0    9        5    6         5         6      4         6           6
1    4        2    7         1         3      4         9           4
2    3        2    1         2         0      7         1           9
```

---

```
cols = ['job','marital','default','housing','loan','contact','month','poutcome']
df = df.join(object_df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).add_suffix('_fac'))

print (df)
   age job marital default  balance housing loan contact  day month  ...  \
0    9   a       a       d        5       d    d       d    6     a  ...   
1    4   a       a       c        2       b    d       d    7     c  ...   
2    3   a       e       e        2       a    e       b    1     b  ...   

   poutcome  conversion  job_fac  marital_fac default_fac  housing_fac  \
0         a           6        0            0           0            0   
1         d           4        0            0           1            1   
2         c           9        0            1           2            2   

   loan_fac  contact_fac  month_fac  poutcome_fac  
0         0            0          0             0  
1         0            0          1             1  
2         1            1          2             2
```

Comment: thank you but it throws me an error: 
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['job_fac', 'marital_fac', 'default_fac', 'housing_fac', 'loan_fac',
       'contact_fac', 'month_fac', 'poutcome_fac'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: yes, i adopted it the way you proposed in your code :(

Comment: @cocoo84hh - there was typo, missing `[` in `cols = [`

Comment: @cocoo84hh - added sample data